# Build fails in teamcity for Nuget packages

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity, nuget

I added to my solution via Nuget the Autoumapper and NUnit packages
and they work great and the project compiles in my computer.

When i declared the build server to build this solution i got this messages:

```
[MSBuild] AutoMapper\AutoMapperSpike.csproj: Build default targets (1s)
[10:35:50][AutoMapper\AutoMapperSpike.csproj] ResolveAssemblyReferences
[10:35:50][ResolveAssemblyReferences] ResolveAssemblyReference
[10:35:50][ResolveAssemblyReference] Primary reference "AutoMapper".
[10:35:50][ResolveAssemblyReference] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360, 9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "AutoMapper". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
[10:35:50][ResolveAssemblyReference]         For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
[10:35:50][ResolveAssemblyReference]         Considered "..\packages\AutoMapper.2.2.1\lib\net40\AutoMapper.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Another thing i noticed is that it creates artificts in build server also with the packages folder.
The only thing it can`t do is build the project in the build server.

Comment: Have you checked in the packages themselves?

Comment: The packages.config and all the projects with project references (including dll added by nuget) are checked-in.

Comment: does the file actually exsist or not?

Answer (score 6):

**In a Visual Studio environment, there’s an option in the UI** that sets a value on your user profile so you never have to remember it again. On a build server, though, there’s no such option. Instead, **you have to set the environment variable “EnableNuGetPackageRestore” to “true” as part of your build.**

I would recommend against trying to set the environment variable inside your build scripts or .csproj files. [Here’s the blog article all about why it happened and what to set on your dev machine/build server.](http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html)

Comment: Hey, i tried setting this environment variable at the build server without success. It is the same problem as before .

Comment: Are you getting the same error as earlier, or any change in the error.?

Comment: Same error.
For now i am using third party library in solution items until i will find a solution to this problem.
I want to work with Nuget as long as it won`t cause problems in the build sever.

Comment: We had a problem like this and it got solved with this. That is why I suggested so. Probably in your case it is missing something more. I am sorry that I am not able to identify that.

Comment: Adding the **`EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true`** environment variable worked for me on our build server (running TeamCity 8.0.2 on Windows XP, of all things). I did have to restart the build agent service though, before it started working. If your agent is running on a different machine to your server, you'd have to do this for each one, I suspect.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure TeamCity actually downloads the package. You can see that in the build history on a single build result page, on the NuGet Packages tab. If you see your package there, then TeamCity is okay with the package.

Next, make sure you can build your project fresh out of the VCS, i.e. take a clean clone and try to build it as such, as that is what TC has to do.

My problem in a very similar scenario was that I had just copied one project into anothers repository and the references where wrong, though the compilation succeeded locally due to cached DLL:s. Uninstalling the package and installing it again from the Visual Studio Package Manager resolved the issue.

Comment: Clean clone revealed my issue. Nice tip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either check in the packages into your VCS or - better - [enable NuGet package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) in your solution.